# Delay between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c

so I'm doing some basic things on XCode when I have this weird bug(?).

There is a little delay between these 2 methods which I can't understand why
[image: Delay time]

Some code that I think it is related.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"changing detail");
    [foodNameText setText:[food objectForKey:kTNFoodName]];
    [restaurantNameText setText: [food objectForKey:kTNRestaurantName]];
}
```

It's not really a big problem but I think it's weird cause my program is very simple so there shouldn't be a timeout for iOS to calculate anything. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: probably the time it takes the view to animate onto the screen versus the time it was instantiated

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin there is nothing on the view except for 4 labels :-?. I don't think it takes that much time :-?

Comment: viewdidload is called before viewdidappear, it's that simple.

Comment: @Alex I know but it shouldn't take nearly 1 second just to load nothing like that. That's the question I'd like to ask!

Comment: viewWillAppear is in the middle. And the animation.

Comment: it's ~500ms, it's probably the animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewController events run in this order...

`- (void)viewDidLoad`
    all objects are instantiated, but geometry (frames etc) is not yet setup correctly.

`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`
Geometry is now correct, view hierarchy is ready for display

> Here transition animations are run as appropriate

`-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`
Animations complete. Hierarchy is displayed as per geometry.

So for example if you use make a custom transition animation object, your animation code will be run after `viewWillAppear` and before `viewDidAppear`.

I have just run some simple tests.

[image]

App launch to VC1

```
2015-01-28 17:47:42.659 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewDidLoad
2015-01-28 17:47:42.660 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewWillAppear
2015-01-28 17:47:42.706 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewDidAppear


   1ms didLoad    -> willAppear
  46ms willAppear -> didAppear
```

Animated "Show" segue from VC1 to VC2.

```
2015-01-28 17:48:52.347 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewDidLoad
2015-01-28 17:48:52.347 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewWillAppear
2015-01-28 17:48:52.851 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewDidAppear

< 1ms didLoad     -> willAppear
504ms willAppear  -> didAppear
```

PushViewController from VC1 to VC2 animated:NO

```
2015-01-28 17:50:31.713 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewDidLoad
2015-01-28 17:50:31.713 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewWillAppear
2015-01-28 17:50:31.714 TestViews[14335:2062491] viewDidAppear

< 1ms didLoad    -> willAppear
  1ms willAppear -> didAppear
```

Animation timing is under the control of the animator. In the case of the 'Show' segue I imagine this is set to 0.5s by design

Comment: First, thanks for explaining to me quite detail about each step. Second, as you said, I added the viewWillAppear method in to check the timeline of it. It does stop for 0.5s after the viewWillAppear method runs. Is there anyway to override this time? And what is your 3rd example? I don't quite get it. Is it using Push segue instead of Show?

Comment: Thanks. I get it now, just by putting the text changing method in viewWillAppear, I can avoid the 0.5s very easy :). I misread this info in my document :). Thanks for showing me exactly what I am doing :)

Comment: @TreeNguyen - the third example uses code to do the transition, instead of a storyboard segue. It is the _same_ as using a "Show" segue, but with the animation turned off to compare timings. It uses `[self.navigationController pushViewController animated:NO]`

Answer (score 2):

sorry couldn't really format as a comment...

the time you aren't accounting for is being used by:

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

log before that...

as to what that is doing, it could be loading data for a view or something... you will have to mess around to see if you can learn what it is doing... set a breakpoint and step in